# Is it possible to get the value of a CString return value (eg. a name) from a SQL stored procedure using ADO and C++

Tags: c++, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado, c-strings

I have been having trouble retrieving the vale us a CString return value. I do not have access to the stored procedure, but, I believe the programmer who wrote it used RETURN NextEDB where NextEDB is a CString. GetRecordCount() = 1 and GetFieldCount() = 1, but, NextEDB has no value. Here is where I setup the return value parameter:

CADOParameter resultParam(CADORecordset::typeVarChar, sizeof(char) * 20, CADOParameter::paramReturnValue);

Here is where I try to retrieve the value:

resultParam.GetValue(NextEDBID)

All of the other code in the function is the same in a bunch of other functions that retrieve declared parameters and all of the other functions work. I am able to retrieve values of return value when they are integers, but, the CString doesn't want to reveal itself. What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The return code of a stored procedure (RETURN statement) is always 32-bit signed integer.  It is intended to indicate success (zero) or non-zero (error/warning) rather than return data.

Consider using an output parameter or result set to return data from the stored procedure rather than return code.  That will provide flexibility with regards the data types.